# Why response can not modify after data has been written in it's output stream

Tags: servlets, cookies, httpresponse

I am struggling with a problem that is as In my application I want to do some modification in response,after data has been written in it's output stream.I want to add a cookie after writing data to it's output stream and flushing that stream. When I  checked response in firebug,I didn't find that cookie in response header.I want to know that why it is happening ??

Answer (score 1):

That's due to how HTTP works. An HTTP response consists of three parts, in this order:

1. The response status code: 200 OK for example
2. A list of headers
3. The body of the response

Setting a cookie consists in adding a header (Set-Cookie) to the response. So, if you have already sent data to the output stream and flushed, the headers have already been sent, as well as some part of, or the whole body. It's thus too late to add a header, since headers have already been sent.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I want to know that is there any solution to add cookie after flushing data. if yes then please tell me solution and Thanks again. –  user2866134 1 hour ago

Comment: No, there's no possibility. You should set the cookie before, or you should bufer the response, then set the cookie, the send the response.